# syslog not logging with local0 and priority on Debian Jessie

Tags: c, debian, syslog, rsyslog

I am running a Debian Jessie server and want to log some custom messages using syslog.  I added the following line to rsyslog.conf
local0.*                       -/var/log/mojosound.log

When I use the syslog function in my c program with this syntax:

```
syslog(LOG_LOCAL0, "Test Message");
```

I see the mojosound.log file created and updated each time I run the sample program.  However, if I try and add a priority to the command, the message goes nowhere that I can find.

```
  int priority = LOG_MAKEPRI(LOG_LOCAL0, LOG_INFO);
  syslog(pritority, "Test Message");
```

There are no other references to local0 in the conf file and no other rules that look like they should matter.

I am thinking that it must be an issue with my conf file but I cannot find anything in the rsyslog documentation that would point to what it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you show your config file when you assume there is something wrong with it?

Comment: may be logging level is not set properly?  try using appropriate level using setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE)); i generally set the local through openlog call.

Comment: Do /var/log/messages see it? And if you increase the priority?

Comment: The conf file is long.  How do I post it?

Comment: Vikram - I will try that and see.  Thanks.

Comment: Giacomo - the messages are not in /var/log/messages.

Comment: Setting the logmask was what I needed.  The messages are now being seen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

rc.local was killing the rsyslog service at the end of startup.  Took a while but finally found it.